# Does the order of a finite group divide the product of degrees of a system of parameters of the invariant algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finite-groups, group-actions, invariant-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $G$ be a subgroup of the finite group $\operatorname{GL}(V)$. Then $G$ acts on the graded algebra $\mathbb{F}(V)$ consisting of polynomial functions on $V$. Then the subalgebra of invariants by $\mathbb{F}[V]^G$ is known to be a finitely generated, graded, connected algebra of Krull dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

In this setting, if there are homogeneous invariants $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^n\deg(f_i)=|G|$ and $\dim(\operatorname{F}[V]^G/(f_1,\ldots,f_n))=0$, then it is known that $\mathbb{F}[V]^G=\mathbb{F}[f_1,\ldots,f_n]$.

More generally, suppose that we have only the condition that $\dim(\mathbb{F}[V]^G/(f_1,\ldots,f_n))=0$. Then are the following statements true?

1. $|G|$ divides $\prod_{i=1}^n\deg(f_i)$.
2. $\mathbb{F}[V]^G$ is a finitely generated free module over $\mathbb{F}[f_1,\ldots,f_n]$ of rank $\prod_{i=1}^n\deg(f_i)/|G|$.

In my explorations of small matrix groups, I seem to be finding both of these statements are true. There must be some general result of this nature.

Thanks for any references or help here.

Comment: Lemma 3.3.1 from [these notes](http://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/pf10/queens/queens_all.pdf) can be useful.

Comment: @user26857:Awesome! That is just about exactly what I needed. So it seems that condition 1 holds in general, and condition 2 is equivalent to the invariant algebra being Cohen-Macaulay. Thanks for this reference.

Comment: Welcome.${}{}{}$